# Where does this proof of the Cantor-Bernstein Theorem use the axiom of choice or principle excluded middle?

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

According to the Cantor-Bernstein Theorem, if $A$ and $B$ are two sets, and there exists injections $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:B\rightarrow A$, then there exists a bijection from A to B.

I recently proved the CB theorem independently by constructing a bijection between the two sets, and I was surprised to learn that apparently a constructive proof of the theorem either requires the Axiom of Choice or the Principle of Excluded Middle, since I didn't think I had used either. I can only conclude that either 1) I used one of those axioms and didn't realize it or 2) my proof doesn't work. Please let me know where I used the AoC or the PEX, or where I made a mistake.

**Proof:** 
Let $A$ and $B$ be sets, and let $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:B\rightarrow A$ be injections. 
 Since the composition of two injections is also an injection, $g\circ{f}:A\rightarrow A$ is also an injection 
$\Rightarrow$ $g\circ f:A\rightarrow (g\circ f)(A)$ is a bijection from A onto a subset of A. 
$\Leftrightarrow\exists$ bijection $\alpha:(g\circ f)(A)\rightarrow A$

 Similarly, $\exists$ bijection $\beta:(f\circ g)(B)\rightarrow B$, with $(f\circ g)(B)\subseteq B$.

Let $b\in (f\circ g)(B)$. Then $b=f(g(b_0))$, some $b_0\in B$. 
 $g(B)\subseteq A \Rightarrow\exists a\in A |a = g(b_0) \Rightarrow\exists x\in(g\circ f)(A) | \alpha (x)=a \Rightarrow f(\alpha(x))=f(g(b_0))=b$.

 So $\phi = f\circ\alpha: (g\circ f)(A)\rightarrow (f\circ g)(B)$ is a surjection, and since it is a composition of injections, $\phi$ is also a bijection.

$\therefore\beta\circ\phi\circ\alpha^{-1}:A\rightarrow B$ is a bijection.

Comment: (1) It's usually called LEM (Law of Excluded Middle); (2) In the standard proof, choice is not used *at all*, and indeed this is one of the remarkable things about the theorem; (3) your proof is not a proof at all, and it is in fact begging the question. Why is there a bijection between $(g\circ f)(A)$ and $A$? That ***is*** the core of the Cantor–Bernstein theorem.

Comment: $(g\circ f)(A)$ is just the image of the composition of g and f, I thought. Restricting the range to just the image makes it a surjection, by definition, since it excludes from the range all elements that have no pre-image.

Comment: @AsafKaragila have I missed something?

Comment: You're composing two injective functions. Why is there a bijection? At what point did you guarantee that those are bijections?

Comment: @AsafKaragila $g\circ f:A\rightarrow A$ is NOT a bijection, but $g\circ f:A\rightarrow im(g\circ f)$ IS a bijection. So for example, if A = N (the naturals),  B = 2N (even naturals), and f = g = 2n, then g(f(x)) = 4x is an injection but NOT a bijection from N to N, but it IS a bijection from N to 4N. This is the idea I used in my argument.

Comment: @AsafKaragila in this case, f(g(B)) would be 8N. Then I show that there is a bijection from 4N to 8N. Finally, I compose the bijections $N\rightarrow 4N\rightarrow 8N \rightarrow 2N$

Comment: Yes, $g\circ f$ is not a bijection. I never claimed that you claimed it is, or that I claim it is. But you claim, out of nowhere, that because that is an injective function from $A$ to $A$, there is a bijective function. Literally, the part with $\exists\alpha\dots$. **WHY** is there such $\alpha$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila oh I understand. Thank you for your patience. 1) it’s not A->A, it’s $im(g\circ f)$ ->A. 2) because $h:X\rightarrow Y$ is a bijection $\Leftrightarrow\exists h^{-1}: Y\rightarrow X$ such that $h\circ h^{-1} = id_X$ and $h^{-1}\circ h= id_Y$

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don’t understand your objection. If I have an injective function $h:X \to Y$ then I can produce from it a bijective function $X \to im(h)$.

Comment: @leibnewtz That is correct. I’m fairly certain Asaf’s objection is that what you said is only correct *because of* a constructive proof via the Cantor-Bernstein theorem or equivalent, so it risks being circular to use it in a proof of CB.

Comment: @FShrike I don’t think there’s any circularity here; it’s bijective by definition.

Comment: @leibnewtz Sure, and I’m not well versed in these things, but it only exists as a constructively defined function per se (I think!) if you prove CB or invoke choice, which you can do without. I think that’s the gist, I’ll be very happy if Asaf weighs in on this.

Comment: @FShrike I’m not entirely sure what you mean. If you want you can easily construct an inverse $j: im(h) \to X$ by defining $j(z)$ to be the unique $x \in X$ such that $h(x)=z$.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake in your proof is when you write "$\phi = f\circ \alpha\colon (g\circ f)(A)\to (f\circ g)(B)$ is a surjection."

In fact, $\phi$ (which is just $g^{-1}$ restricted to $(g\circ f)(A)$) is a surjection onto $f(A)$, not onto the smaller set $(f\circ g)(B)$. So it establishes a bijection between $(g\circ f)(A)$ and $f(A)$. This proves nothing, since both of these sets are already in bijection with $A$.

Comment: I see what you mean, but it’s a bit alarming. What, theoretically, would need to happen to fix the hole?

Comment: @ZacharyF A completely new proof idea.